# XMPPFramework extension for delayed delivery time

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xmppframework

I want to show time label on my chat. But I can't find data-time after parser.
Is it possible to add extensions to my lib to get a time?

I use https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework
And simple client example.

There is the extensions I want to use XEP-0203 (XMPPElement+Delay.h).

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile in `XMPPElement+Delay.m` and add the line for `XMPPElement+Delay.h` to your `XMPPFramework.h`.
2. In your delegate class, put code in `-xmppStream:didReceiveMessage` that invokes `[message delayedDeliveryDate]` and log the result. Make sure you `#import "XMPPFramework.h"`.
3. If you're getting a proper date, use NSDateFormatter to render it to a string as you like. If you're not, probably need to log out the entire message find out if the server is correctly sending the dates.